# How do topics get pinned to the Community Bulletin?

Tags: support, stackexchange, community-bulletin

Basic information-gathering in this post.

- Where is the Community Bulletin?
- Is there a bigger board than what is floating on the right-hand side of the screen?
- How do you put a post/thread there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This MSO post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129483/new-community-bulletin-box-in-side-area) explains the community bulletin.  Below refers to how the entries are populated:

> Moderators and select Stack Exchange employees can add new events from
>   the Mod Links menu, giving each entry a title and beginning and ending
>   date & time. Each entry must be linked to a Stack Exchange property (a
>   Stack Exchange main site or meta post, Blog Overflow blog post, or a
>   post on the main Stack Exchange blog).
>
> If no entries have been manually submitted to be displayed, the
>   Community Bulletin will be populated with [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) and active meta
>   posts.